# Laravel File Manager UniSharp Incorrect Image URL

Tags: laravel, file-manager

[image]

[image]
Displayed Image URL is incorrect. It should add "public/" in the url. How can I edit the url?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing in public, I remove base directory as following:

```
 'base_directory' => '',
 'images_folder_name' => 'photos',
 'files_folder_name' => 'files',
 'shared_folder_name' => 'shares',
 'thumb_folder_name' => 'thumbs',
```

And edit `LfmHelpers.php` under traits in line 113 as following: 
`$prefix = '/' . $prefix;` And it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

If a UNISHARP then you need to have a look at this issue [UNISHARP BUG](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager/issues/102) as it suggest it is a bug.

The issue reporter find the solution by doing so

> It worked after I removed the following from
>   vendor/unisharp/laravel-filemanager/src/views/script.blade.php
>
> if (path.indexOf(ds) === 0) { path = path.substring(1); }

Hope it will solve yours.

Comment: I am using UniSharp file manager... where can i edit that image location url?

Comment: Instead of storing in public, I remove base directory as following:'base_directory' => '',

    'images_folder_name' => 'photos',
    'files_folder_name'  => 'files',

    'shared_folder_name' => 'shares',
    'thumb_folder_name'  => 'thumbs', And edit LfmHelpers.php in line 113 as following: $prefix = '/' . $prefix; And it works fine now.